# Ubuntu 16.04 boots significantly slower than any earlier version

Tags: boot, 16.04

I am on a DELL Precision 5510 with this specs:

- 32GB of RAM
- Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8
- 1TB SSD
- OS Type 64bit

The boot process takes very long, much longer than any Ubuntu version before. There are several similiar questions here on Askubuntu. However, most of them lack an answer. Plus, the issues seem to be very individually and thus, very different.

This is what `dmsg > boot.txt` says after 3 seconds:

```
[    2.907012] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.186454] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    3.186595] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    3.186700] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ron-Precision-5510>.
[    3.239287] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.239322] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    3.239357] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    3.239364] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    3.239410] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    3.239452] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dcryptsetup.slice.
[    3.239547] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.239559] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.239564] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    3.239580] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.239585] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    3.239620] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    3.239632] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    3.239660] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.239688] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    3.239692] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    3.239711] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    3.239937] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    3.240228] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    3.240554] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    3.241415] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    3.241667] systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
[    3.242125] systemd[1]: Started Read required files in advance.
[    3.242285] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    3.242643] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[    3.242695] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    3.243342] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    3.243653] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    3.245163] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    3.245522] systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
[    3.245708] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    3.245812] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    3.245907] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    3.245995] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    3.250219] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    3.251704] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    3.254661] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    3.261359] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    3.261678] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    3.261968] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    3.262733] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    3.263991] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    3.297023] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    3.312048] systemd-journald[295]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    3.353474] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.IETM._ART: Return Package type mismatch at index 0 - found Integer, expected Reference (20150930/nspredef-297)
[    3.353481] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
[    3.353483] _ART package 0 is invalid, ignoredACPI Warning: \_SB_.IETM._TRT: Return Package has no elements (empty) (20150930/nsprepkg-126)
[    3.357657] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    3.364794] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.364806] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    3.364807] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.364810] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.364812] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.364816] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.373681] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.373684] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.373685] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.373686] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.373687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.373688] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.373733] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.373746] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    3.373748] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.383616] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.386304] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    3.388847] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.396047] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    3.396228] input: HID 046a:0023 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046A:0023.0002/input/input10
[    3.396470] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    3.397178] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[    3.397550] idma64 idma64.0: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[    3.400472] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:04F3:21D5.0004/input/input11
[    3.402186] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[    3.402188] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.402189] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.402190] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.402190] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.402193] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.403949] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    3.406496] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    3.406498] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    3.406553] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.407462] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.407473] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.407482] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.407780] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    3.409232] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    3.412056] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (1bcf:2b95)
[    3.412099] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.412339] idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[    3.416365] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.421072] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input12
[    3.428893] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.428896] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    3.429015] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.431460] Adding 33393660k swap on /dev/nvme0n1p4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:33393660k SSFS
[    3.435183] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    3.435185] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    3.439596] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.444242] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    3.444310] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    3.444417] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    3.444583] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 243
[    3.444595] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    3.444671] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    3.444684] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  361.42  Tue Mar 22 18:10:58 PDT 2016
[    3.450514] cherry 0003:046A:0023.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 046a:0023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    3.450855] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:21D5.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input0
[    3.451224] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.451226] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    3.451642] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.451644] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    3.451645] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    3.451646] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    3.452411] input: HID 046a:0023 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046A:0023.0003/input/input14
[    3.458745] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
[    3.470173] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.470300] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915_bpo])
[    3.508203] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input15
[    3.509244] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[    3.539479] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3266: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    3.539482] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.539484] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.539486] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.539487] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.539489] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x18
[    3.539491] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
[    3.539493] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    3.539508] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.908:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=682 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.579758] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.948:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=685 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.579983] cherry 0003:046A:0023.0003: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 046a:0023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[    3.582254] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.948:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=678 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.582260] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.948:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=678 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.583029] dell_laptop: Using i8042 filter function for receiving events
[    3.583416] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.948:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=691 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.584015] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.948:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=692 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.588420] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.952:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=699 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.588451] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.952:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app" pid=683 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.588457] audit: type=1400 audit(1466404548.952:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app//oxide_helper" pid=683 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.599384] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    3.599387] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    3.599388] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    3.599390] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.599392] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.599393] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.599395] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.599397] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    3.599398] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    3.599399] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.599401] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    3.601737] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[    3.601838] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[    3.601917] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[    3.602016] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[    3.604364] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  361.42  Tue Mar 22 17:29:54 PDT 2016
[    3.616616] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in lite mode, major device number 242
[    3.623344] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.623385] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.623408] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.623429] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.623450] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.623482] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.623509] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.652047] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    3.726019] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[    3.726052] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.726139] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-19)
[    3.727471] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.759682] input: DLL06E5:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-DLL06E5:01/0018:06CB:7A13.0005/input/input20
[    3.759766] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:7A13.0005: input,hidraw4: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DLL06E5:01 06CB:7A13] on i2c-DLL06E5:01
[    3.878403] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   93.305893] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   93.318665] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
[   93.318667] _ART package 0 is invalid, ignored
[   93.318680] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
[   93.318682] _ART package 0 is invalid, ignored
[   93.334787] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   93.334789] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   93.334792] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   93.561380] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   93.561466] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   93.561725] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   93.706086] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   93.706431] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   93.783642] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   93.800490] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   93.800495] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   93.800500] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[   93.800507] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   93.800558] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   93.800877] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[   93.898711] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   94.328351] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   94.331923] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.331978] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.332002] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.332022] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.332043] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.332074] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.332094] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.335196] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   94.350824] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   94.361165] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   94.385587] Ebtables v2.0 registered
[   94.525536] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-2aab5f16-8246-e142-9e85-24cf66dd2449) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[   94.525617] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-2aab5f16-8246-e142-9e85-24cf66dd2449) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[   94.621407] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   94.684423] device virbr0-nic entered promiscuous mode
[   94.833169] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
[   94.885554] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[   94.885566] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[   94.947817] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[   94.950086] device virbr0-nic left promiscuous mode
[   94.950109] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[   95.316452] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   96.933543] wlp2s0: authenticate with 5c:49:79:5e:b2:55
[   96.942271] wlp2s0: send auth to 5c:49:79:5e:b2:55 (try 1/3)
[   96.948025] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   96.948303] wlp2s0: associate with 5c:49:79:5e:b2:55 (try 1/3)
[   96.952720] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 5c:49:79:5e:b2:55 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   96.961974] wlp2s0: associated
[   96.962011] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[   97.041910] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by 5c:49:79:5e:b2:55
```

However, I have no clue how to extract valuable information from this.

The output of `systemd-analyze plot > systemd-analyze.html` can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xgemu8u4/). From what I can see here, there is a gap of about 90 seconds between `sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:02:00.0-net-wlp2s0.device` and `sysinit.target` where absolutely nothing happens. And `apt-daily.services` seems to take 47 seconds to be activated.

If these two matters are main causes for the slow boot process, what can I do to speed them up? Could you spot any issues else?